# Syntax error with group by keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a SQL query but I am getting error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by t.status
>   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1.

However it's working fine without group by, can some help me to resolve this problem.

Here is the query (little big one  :-))

```
SELECT 
        count(t.status) as counts, 
        (
            SELECT attribute_values 
            FROM product_attribute_values pav 
            WHERE attr_name = 'Brand' 
            AND contract_id = c.id 
            AND product_id = c.product 
            AND pav.sp_id = c.sp_id
        ) as make_brand, 
        (
            SELECT group_concat(sc.short_name) 
            FROM contract_product_service_centers cpsc 
            LEFT JOIN service_centers sc ON cpsc.service_center_id = sc.id AND cpsc.sp_id = sc.sp_id 
            WHERE sc.sp_id = c.sp_id 
            AND cpsc.contract_id = c.contract_id 
            AND cpsc.service_center_id IN (1, 14, 3, 4)
        ) as service_center_name,
        (
            SELECT attribute_values 
            FROM product_attribute_values pav1 
            WHERE attr_name='Model' 
            and contract_id=c.id 
            and product_id=c.product 
            and pav1.sp_id=c.sp_id
        ) as model, 
        (
            SELECT supervisor_id 
            FROM `user_links` ul, contract_product_service_centers cpsc 
            where ul.service_center_id=cpsc.service_center_id 
            and ul.sp_id=cpsc.sp_id 
            and ul.sp_id=cpsc.sp_id 
            and ul.category_id=c.category 
            and ul.sp_id=c.sp_id 
            and cpsc.contract_id=c.contract_id
        ) as linked_sup,assigned_sup_id, 
        assigned_se_id, 
        assigned_by, 
        date_format(t.datecreated, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as created_date, 
        date_format(closeddate, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as closed_date, 
        date_format(assigned_datetime, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as tkt_assigned_datetime, 
        datediff(current_Date, date(t.datecreated)) as days_since_tkt_created, 
        p.ct_template_id, 
        (
            select ct_f.name 
            from forms ct_f 
            where ct_f.id=p.ct_template_id
        ) as ct_template_name, 
        p.mt_template_id, 
        (
            select mt_f.name 
            from forms mt_f 
            where mt_f.id=p.mt_template_id
        ) as mt_template_name 
FROM tickets t 
left join contracts c on t.contract_id=c.contract_id and t.sub_contract_no=c.sub_contract_no and t.sp_id=c.sp_id 
left join products p on c.product=p.id left join product_categories pc on c.category=pc.id and p.category_id=pc.id 
where t.status in (2,5,6) 
and t.sp_id='VIV74' 
and c.category in (1,12,2) 
and c.contract_id in ('CN10001') 
and ( t.ticket_id='CT100001') 
and ( t.ticket_display_status='Accept Closure') 
and ( p.product_short_name ='LAP') 
and ( pc.short_name ='ELE') 
and ( firstname ='Rajesh Kumar') 
and ( c.contract_id='CN10001') 
having service_center_name in ('SCONE','SC-01') 
and days_since_tkt_created in ('44','43','39') 
and make_brand in ('lg','samsung') 
and model in ('23','46') 
group by t.status
```

Comment: Reduce your query to the core problem

Comment: if you want to group by `t.status`, then that should be the only one you should be selecting, besides `counts`.

Comment: thxs for the replay muratgu, i tried like what you said, but still its showing same error

Comment: Are you sure you did copy-and-paste the whole select? (I see no LIMIT there....)

Comment: Im sure, but my query not having LIMIT, I don't know from where its comes

Comment: `i tried what you said`... no you haven't. maybe you should read about how `group by` works first.

Comment: I removed all select, and add only one count and  stick with conditions as it is ...SELECT count(t.status) as counts FROM tickets t left join contracts c on t.contract_id=c.contract_id and t.sub_contract_no=c.sub_contract_no and t.sp_id=c.sp_id left join products p on c.product=p.id left join product_categories pc on c.category=pc.id and p.category_id=pc.id where t.status in (2,5,6) and t.sp_id='VIV74' and c.category in (1,12,2) and c.contract_id in ('CN10001','CN10002','CN10003','CN10005','CN10006','CN10007','CN10008','CN10009','CN10010','CN10011','CN10012','CN10013','CN1001.....

Comment: is that right? muratgu

Comment: There's no way that this query is 'working fine'!! Let's start over. What are you trying to do? Provide CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result.

Comment: Thxs for the reply strawberry, its working fine when i execute without group by.  I have 3 types of status called active,inactive,closed in status column, I just want to get count of distinct values of status when ever its executed, this query used for filter purpose, I need to show the count of records after filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `having` clause should be after the `group by` clause.
Of course, having this massive wall of code doesn't make it easy to debug it, but that's the first thing that popped before my eyes when editing your question.

```
SELECT 
        count(t.status) as counts, 
        (
            SELECT attribute_values 
            FROM product_attribute_values pav 
            WHERE attr_name = 'Brand' 
            AND contract_id = c.id 
            AND product_id = c.product 
            AND pav.sp_id = c.sp_id
        ) as make_brand, 
        (
            SELECT group_concat(sc.short_name) 
            FROM contract_product_service_centers cpsc 
            LEFT JOIN service_centers sc ON cpsc.service_center_id = sc.id AND cpsc.sp_id = sc.sp_id 
            WHERE sc.sp_id = c.sp_id 
            AND cpsc.contract_id = c.contract_id 
            AND cpsc.service_center_id IN (1, 14, 3, 4)
        ) as service_center_name,
        (
            SELECT attribute_values 
            FROM product_attribute_values pav1 
            WHERE attr_name='Model' 
            and contract_id=c.id 
            and product_id=c.product 
            and pav1.sp_id=c.sp_id
        ) as model, 
        (
            SELECT supervisor_id 
            FROM `user_links` ul, contract_product_service_centers cpsc 
            where ul.service_center_id=cpsc.service_center_id 
            and ul.sp_id=cpsc.sp_id 
            and ul.sp_id=cpsc.sp_id 
            and ul.category_id=c.category 
            and ul.sp_id=c.sp_id 
            and cpsc.contract_id=c.contract_id
        ) as linked_sup,assigned_sup_id, 
        assigned_se_id, 
        assigned_by, 
        date_format(t.datecreated, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as created_date, 
        date_format(closeddate, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as closed_date, 
        date_format(assigned_datetime, '%d-%b-%Y %I:%i %p') as tkt_assigned_datetime, 
        datediff(current_Date, date(t.datecreated)) as days_since_tkt_created, 
        p.ct_template_id, 
        (
            select ct_f.name 
            from forms ct_f 
            where ct_f.id=p.ct_template_id
        ) as ct_template_name, 
        p.mt_template_id, 
        (
            select mt_f.name 
            from forms mt_f 
            where mt_f.id=p.mt_template_id
        ) as mt_template_name 
FROM tickets t 
left join contracts c on t.contract_id=c.contract_id and t.sub_contract_no=c.sub_contract_no and t.sp_id=c.sp_id 
left join products p on c.product=p.id left join product_categories pc on c.category=pc.id and p.category_id=pc.id 
where t.status in (2,5,6) 
and t.sp_id='VIV74' 
and c.category in (1,12,2) 
and c.contract_id in ('CN10001') 
and ( t.ticket_id='CT100001') 
and ( t.ticket_display_status='Accept Closure') 
and ( p.product_short_name ='LAP') 
and ( pc.short_name ='ELE') 
and ( firstname ='Rajesh Kumar') 
and ( c.contract_id='CN10001') 
group by t.status
having service_center_name in ('SCONE','SC-01') 
and days_since_tkt_created in ('44','43','39') 
and make_brand in ('lg','samsung') 
and model in ('23','46')
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)